Laravel mail with custom setup
Our mail service works fine with mailtrap for example and successfully communicates with the usual providers.
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.mydomain.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mydomainemailpassword
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@mydomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="XYZ"
MAIL_DOMAIN=mailhandler.local

MAIL_DOMAIN is not part of the env file...
However, it requires an additional parameter - mailhandler.local
And...Laravel does not take this field...how to approach this
MAIL_DOMAIN is where we have it and try passing it to mail config...but no dice.
'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'url' => env('MAIL_URL'),
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'domain' => env('MAIL_DOMAIN'), // Custom domain entry
        ],

Any suggestions? It's tied to an outlook or office365 setup.

Thanks for your assistance.

It won't work like this. you need add it MAIL_DOMAIN on smtp config before sending mail.

why can't you use local_domain in the config? 'local_domain' => env('MAIL_DOMAIN'),

Local domain was a custom attempt we tried also. That isn't part of the default file.

what mail service are you using, do you have any documentation for why mailhandler.local is required?

No access to any docs but it's using outlook/office365 at it's core.

@jackbauer how do you know you need "mailhandler.local". It is hard to debug without proper requirements/docs

Which service you're trying to set up, like Outlook, Mailgun, or something else? That would be great!

Haven't been given any docs. But the service is either exchange/ or outlook. I've attached an image for setup on mobile.
